# python sympy print command scientific exponential prefix formatting

Tags: python, printf, sympy, equation-solving

I use python with scientific libraries for electrical engineering studies at university. I want to format output of print command with 3 step scientific exponential prefix notation. I solve an equation and substitute values in it.

Example:

```
import sympy as smp
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
eqn = Eq(Z, (G1/(G1**2 + (w*C)**2)) + R2)
a = solve(eqn, C)
x = a[0]
z = round(x.subs([(G1, 2.5e-3), (Z, 200), (w, 2*np.pi*800), (R2, 80)]).evalf(), 20)
print("%.4le" %z)
```

Output:

`7.5973e-07`

I use printf formatting from c language.

| Prefix | Power |
| --- | --- |
| milli | `e-03` |
| micro | `e-06` |
| nano | `e-09` |

My question is how can I format exponent in print output in 3 step scientific prefix notation like figure above?

Output should be like:

`759.73e-09`

Can anybody show me code to fix that? It is clear for me that I can change notation by myself but I want handle it with computer so I avoid calculate.